# How to reset an integer counter on every refresh page

Tags: javascript

Hi guys hope you are doing well, I have been having issues with my my integer counter not resetting after I refresh my page. I am using the numCorrect to store the values and I was wondering if there is any way that I could pass in a function on window reload and have numCorrect reset to 0. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much and have a good day!

```
router.post("/result", (req, res) => {
  // compared key answer which is from Questions data to the users answers using req.body

  for (var i = 0; i < Questions.length; i++) {
    let userAnswer = "";
    let numCorrect = 0;
    userAnswer = req.body[i + 1];
    let keyAnswer = Questions[i].answer;

    if (userAnswer === keyAnswer) {
      numCorrect++;
    }
  }

  res.json({
    // needs a function to check whether the use passed or failed
    summary: checker(),

    score: numCorrect,

    total: countNum(),
  });
});
```

Comment: This question should maybe be tagged with NodeJS instead of just JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Your code will always return score 1 every time when answer is true in last question because you declare variable inside the loop.

your code should be like this :

```
router.post("/result", (req, res) => {

  let numCorrect = 0;    

  for (var i = 0; i < Questions.length; i++) {
    let userAnswer = "";

    userAnswer = req.body[i + 1];
    let keyAnswer = Questions[i].answer;

    if (userAnswer === keyAnswer) {
      numCorrect++;
    }
  }

  res.json({
    // needs a function to check whether the use passed or failed
    summary: checker(),

    score: numCorrect,

    total: countNum(),
  });
});
```

So that, when new route match every time, `numCorrect` will reset to 0 and then loop will make increase `numCorrect` value based on correct answer.